# LG TV funky psychedelic color display

Tags: repair, television

I turned on my LG TV last month and the colors are completely wrong. I tried a picture reset, I tried unplugging it for a prolonged period of time, I tried changing out the HDMI cable. So far nothing I have tried has worked. I know it isn't an issue with the Apple TV since I plugged it into another monitor and the colors were fine. I attempted a "Hard reset without a remote" instructions that I found online and I have not had any additional success. Is this just something that happens to TVs as they age or is there anything else I can try? To me the image being so pixelated just feels like there is something I am missing.

The model number is 42LC7D and I followed instructions (as best as practical) on https://www.wikihow.com/Restart-an-Lg-TV about resetting my tv.

[image]

Comment: It's either under warranty, or it's junk. Welcome to modern electronics.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about home improvement within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Sorry, it's junk. This is an OLD TV. It has Amazon reviews dated 2008! It could easily be 15 years old. I thought my 2012 Samsung TV was old!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If under warranty, contact the manufacturer for repair.

If not, contact the manufacturer/search the web and hope this has a known fix.

Or try to find a hardware hacker who wants to play with it. Depending on just what it's doing, I would pay a few bucks for it and hope to at least salvage the LCD panel...